# When and why did the output of qr() change?

Tags: regex, perl

The output of perl's `qr` has changed, apparently sometime between versions 5.10.1 and 5.14.2, and the change is not documented--at least not fully.

To demonstrate the change, execute the following one-liner on each version:

```
perl -e 'print qr(foo)is."\n"'
```

Output from perl 5.10.1-17squeeze6 (Debian squeeze):

```
(?-xism:foo)
```

Output from perl 5.14.2-21+deb7u1 (Debian wheezy):

```
(?^:foo)
```

The perl documentation (`perldoc perlop`) says:

> $rex = qr/my.STRING/is;
>   print $rex;                 # prints (?si-xm:my.STRING)
>   s/$rex/foo/;

which appears to no longer be true:

```
$ perl -e 'print qr/my.STRING/is."\n"'
(?^si:my.STRING)
```

I would like to know when this change occurred (which version of Perl, or supporting library or whatever).

Some background, in case it's relevant:

This change has caused a bunch of unit tests to fail. I need to decide if I should simply update the unit tests to reflect the new format, or make the tests dynamic enough to support both formats, etc. To make an informed decision, I would like to understand why the change took place. Knowing when and where it took place seems like the best place to start in that investigation.

Comment: Your terminology, or maybe your understanding of what `qr` does, is not quite right.  It's not right to say "the output of `qr`".  `qr` is an operator that creates a regex object.  What changed is the stringification of regexes.  `qr`'s behavior has not changed.

Comment: @AndyLester: If you want to get technical, the output *did* change--at least in cases where any of the new regex modifiers are used. But that's really beside the point. You understood what the question meant, right? And I suspect expressing it in a way that may be more literally correct would lose meaning for a large number of people who may search for this answer in the future.

Comment: `qr` has no output.  It returns an object.  The "output", or the stringification of that object, is what has changed.  In the case of `print qr/foo/i`, the stringification is implicit.

Comment: @AndyLester: Alright. You win the game of semantics. I hope you feel happy :)

Comment: `qr` has output in the same way that `stringification` has output. That is, it returns something.  Strictly speaking, that's just a return value (same as automatic stringification). But if you're willing to call stringification "output", then the object that qr returns is also "output"--and that has changed.

Comment: We are computer programmers.  Precision is everything.  Language, or "semantics", informs how we think about things, and how we interact with others when discussing these topics.

Comment: @AndyLester: Your own language is imprecise--and ironically, in precisely the same way mine was for which you were criticizing my question.

Comment: I think the title of the question accurately conveys the actual question--even (and perhaps especially) when taking specifics of language in mind. Rewording it to "When and why did the stringification of regex objects change?" would obscure the question to all but those most intimately familiar with perl. And saying "When and why did the stringification of qr's return value change?" would also add more (IMO) unnecessary detail, for no real gain.

Comment: And calling the result of `print qr()` "qr's output" doesn't really seem that inaccurate anyway... it is outputing a string that came from `qr`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's documented in [`perl5140delta`](http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta#construct-signifies-default-modifiers):

> **Regular Expressions**
>
> `(?^...)` construct signifies default modifiers
>
> [...] Stringification of regular expressions now uses this notation. [...]
>
> This change is likely to break code that compares stringified regular expressions with fixed strings containing `?-xism`.

The function [`regexp_pattern`](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#regexp_pattern%28%24ref%29) can be used to parse the modifiers for normalisation purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Part of the reason this was added, was that regular expressions were getting quite a few new modifiers.

Your example would actually produce something like this if that change didn't happen:

```
(?d-xismpaul:foo)
```

That also doesn't really express the modifiers in place.

`d`/`u`/`l` can only be added to a regex, not subtracted like `i`.
They are also mutually exclusive.

`a`/`aa` There are actually two levels for this modifier.

---

While work went underway adding these modifiers it was determined that this will break quite a few tests on CPAN modules. 
Seeing as the tests were going to break anyway, it was agreed upon that there should be a way of specifying *just use the defaults* (`(?^:…)`). 
That way, the tests wouldn't have to updated every time a new modifier was added.

Answer (score -1):

To receive the stringified form of a regexp you can use [Regexp::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aParser) and its `qr` method. Using this module you can not only test the representation of a regexp, but also walk a tree.

Comment: That's interesting, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Correct. But this can help you, as a TS, to look at the problem at another angle: maybe instead of testing _representation_, you can test the _functionality_ (either by traversing the tree, or comparing it to a test tree). This way you'll make your code bullet-proof against any future incompatible Perl re engine changes (in the representational sense only, of course).

Comment: It should be a comment, not an answer.